# Java Objects: Method doesn't print as it should

Tags: java, object

I have two classes: Apartments and Building. The Apartment class:

```
public class Apartment {
    private String familyName;
    private int rent;
    private boolean isRented;
}
```

The Building class has an Apartment array, and a numOfApartments variable which indicates how many apartments the building has, and also a FINAL variable who indicates the max number for apartments in one building.

```
private Apartment[] apartments;
private int numOfApartments;
private final int MAX_APARTMENTS=20;

public Building() {
    this.apartments=new Apartment[MAX_APARTMENTS];
    this.numOfApartments=0;
}
```

Now I want to make a method which raises the rent for an apartment by an amount which is taken as parameter:

```
public void raiseRent(int amount) {
    for (int i=0; i<numOfApartments; i++) {
        apartments[i].setRent(apartments[i].getRent() + amount);
    }
}
```

the addAppartment method:

```
public boolean addApartment(Apartment a){ //adds an appartment to the building if
                                           //there's enough space in the array.
        if (this.numOfApartments<this.MAX_APARTMENTS)
        {
            this.apartments[this.numOfApartments]=new Apartment(a);
            this.numOfApartments++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**The apartment class string ToString method:**

```
public String toString()
{
    if (this.isRented) //if the apartment is rented, prints:
    {
        return "Apartment rent: " + this.rent + ". rented to " + this.familyName + " family.";
    }
    else
        return "Apartment rent: " + this.rent  + ". not rented yet.";
}
```

The main is:

```
String familyName; int rent;
System.out.println("enter family name and rent by this order");
familyName=scan.next();
rent=scan.nextInt();

Apartment a=new Apartment(familyName,rent);  //build new apartment object.
Building b=new Building();
System.out.println(b.addApartment(a));
b.raiseRent(200); //initiate the raiseRent method.
```

Everything here works, but when I write this:

```
 System.out.println(a);
```

The rent is shown as the old rent, not the updated one. 
When I write this:

```
System.out.println(b.apartments[0]);
```

It works.

Why when I write System.out.println(a); it doesn't work?

Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Please show the code for `addApartment`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight method added.

Comment: Why `this.apartments[this.numOfApartments]=new Apartment(a);` rather than `apartments[this.numOfApartments] = a;`?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I suspect this is some kind of homework or other learning exercise to teach pass-by-value.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - it fixed the problem! thank you. can you please explain why did it create the problem in my code?

Comment: @Doug - you're almost right. not homework - but I had a lecture about pass-by-value which I didn't quite understand...

Comment: @Assaf - My [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14663298/284051) explains it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your

`public boolean addApartment(Apartment a)` method:

```
this.apartments[this.numOfApartments]=new Apartment(a);
```

Creates a new apartment which appears to be constructed from an existing apartment. This is a copy.

After you raise the rent, the

`Apartment a=new Apartment(familyName,rent);  //build new apartment object.`

That you passed in to

`b.addApartment(a)`

Will not have an updated rent. This is because Java is pass-by-value. It's a "new" `int` in the `new Apartment` your Building `Apartment[]` collection contains, even if you set it from an existing one (`this.rent = other.rent`)

Comment: And my new code: this.apartments[this.numOfApartments]=a; sends a copy of the a object to my array, and not the original?

Comment: Not quite - it stores a copy of the *value* of `a` - which is a reference. The object (instance) remains the same and is now shared within the `Building.apartments` collection, and whatever part of your program all this is being called from (e.g. `main`). This means that changes you make to the apartment either from the building or from `a` would be to the same object instance. As @dasblinkenlight pointed out, this isn't always a good thing - sharing state (access to objects) can present its own set of challenges.

Comment: So does it mean I have now created aliasing for the a object? If that the case, that is not what I wanted to achieve... Is there a way to make my goal without aliasing?

Comment: What *is* the goal? I mean, you can either alias the `a` object and share it inside and outside of the `Building` instance or you have different `Apartment` instances and that's that. Do you see what I mean? Perhaps if I better understand your goal I can answer you more clearly.

Comment: First, I want to add the a apartment to my Building array. The a object is an apartment which I recieve as a parameter. Then, I want to raise the rent of the apartments in the building, including a, and print the new rent. Thank you again.

Comment: Then you are inherently trying to create an alias. Your Building's array and your `a` reference have to point to the same Apartment instance if you want changes made by Building (to the apartments in the array) to reflect on `a` as well. The advice about avoiding this is important to heed, but it's also not necessarily relevant to your learning exercise.

Comment: Note that I wouldn't necessarily program it this way. I might instead have an `Apartment` be an immutable object with properties like apartmentNumber, floorNumber, numberOfBedrooms, numberOfBathrooms, size, etc. -- then I might have a `Building` contain a pre-defined `Set<Apartment>` and a `Map<Apartment, Lease>` where `Lease` contains details about the duration and rent. My `raiseRent` method would look at each lease and replace it (immutability). That also allows you to find out if a Lease exists for a given Apartment (or findAvailableApartmentsForLease) and so on. Just food for thought.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `addApartment` method: rather than adding the `Apartment` object passed in to the array, you add a brand-new object created with `new` by calling a copy constructor. This breaks the connection between the variable called `a` that you passed in and the element at index zero of the `apartments` array, explaining the difference in printed values.

The copy semantic that you have in the `addApartment` is actually a good thing: it saves you from unusual aliasing later on, because the implementation is no longer dependent on the callers to pass distinct objects. Changing the code to

```
apartments[this.numOfApartments] = a; // No copy
```

creates problems, because `Apartment` is *mutable*. Consider this call sequence:

```
Apartment a = new Apartment();
for (int i = 100 ; i <= 1000 ; i += 100) {
    a.setRent(i);
    building.addApartment(a);
}
```

One would expect ten apartments, with rents 100 to 1000 to be added. With a no-copy change, however, you would end up with ten identical apartments, all with rent set to 1000. This is because under the hood all ten items in the `apartment` array would reference the same `Apartment` object - the one you created before the `for` loop. This causes numerous headaches down the road, so it is better to keep the copying code in place, and know that rent increases should be checked on the objects inside the building, not on the objects that you passed into the `addApartment` method.

Comment: The `new Apartment` is constructed with a reference to the existing `Apartment` - assuming the rent, family name and such are copied out, you haven't explained why this doesn't work.

Comment: @Doug Still it's a new object. The rent is raised on the *copy* apartment object, not on the original one. Once the copy is constructed, it lives its life independently of the original that has been passed into `new Arartment(a)`.

Comment: Precisely. Your answer doesn't actually explain *why* it works that way. `int x = 0; int y = x; y = 1` can let `x` = 0 or `x` = 1 depending on the semantics of the language. The fact the question exists inherently suggests that the poster is trying to understand how the pass-by-value semantics work in Java. Your answer doesn't explain why, it just says, "it's good that it doesn't work the way you expected" in so many words. The copy semantic is inherent in Java for a primitive type, so it wasn't *intentional*, hence the confusion.

Comment: @Doug I do not know if copying was or was not intentional: the code of `addApartment` could be coming from somebody else as part of a learning assignment.

Comment: That's right, but since the poster is performing a copy-construction of an object, then expecting the changes made in the copy to reflect in the original, is suggests a lack of understanding of how Java works with respect to these things. Therefore, I consider your answer to be lacking if it does not address those concepts. You've said what happens, you've said it's good it happens, but you haven't said why it happens.

Comment: -- Which is to say, you're basically assuming that someone understands the imperative nature of Java. That isn't necessarily something obvious to those who are just starting out or coming from another field. They may see `y = x` as a means of aliasing and thus expect that the `rent` in the `new Apartment(a)` is just a reference to one shared value. (I didn't say `new int` so why is it a new int?)